# VB6 WINHTTP proxy freezez ui?

Tags: vb6

here is my code below , when i use it without proxy it runs smooth but when i start to use proxy the UI freezez for a bit , kindly tell me if their is something that can be done so it dont freeze and be able to do other stuff while its doing its thing.

```
Function httpreq(url As String) As String
    Dim whr As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

Set whr = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   whr.Open "GET", url, False
whr.SetProxy 2, List1.Text, ""
    whr.Send
    httpreq = whr.ResponseText
    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & whr.ResponseText
End Function
```