# win http get request using proxy freezing the user interface and dont work

Tags: vb6

i am able to make connection when i use 1 ip how ever when i try and use all the ip in list1 then ui freezez.

thier is only 20 ip in list1

```
RichTextBox1.Text = ""
Dim lngI As Long
For lngI = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
If Combo1.ListIndex = Combo1.ListCount - 1 Then
        Combo1.ListIndex = 0

    Else
        Combo1.ListIndex = Combo1.ListIndex + 1
        Text2.Text = Combo1.Text
    End If
'       Text1.Text = ""
   Dim result As String
Dim url As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
url = "https://example.com"
winHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False
'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "SonyEricssonT618/R401 Profile/MIDP-1.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", Text2.Text
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
'winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Keep-Alive", "115"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
winHttpReq.SetProxy 2, List1.List(lngI), ""
winHttpReq.Send
'result = winHttpReq.ResponseText
   'RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & winHttpReq.Status & vbCrLf & winHttpReq.GetAllResponseHeaders & vbCrLf & winHttpReq.ResponseText
List2.AddItem GetBetween(winHttpReq.ResponseText, Text4.Text, Text5.Text, , False) & vbCrLf
 Next lngI
 Set winHttpReq = Nothing
```

the site am connecting to is https so winsock is no good at this time unless its possible

Comment: will appreciate if anybody can suggest me alternative method or maybe fix this

Comment: have you tried debugging it to see where it hangs?

Comment: The UI will freeze during work because everything in VB6 is happening on a single thread.  One way to mitigate this between heavily blocking operations like .Send is to put a call to DoEvents somewhere within the loop.

Comment: Is this the same as your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226634/vb6-winhttp-proxy-freezez-ui ?